# Xamarin.Mac -- AppDelegate DidFinishLaunching -- Is the "Main Interface" specified in Info.plist already supposed to be loaded?

Tags: appdelegate, appkit, info.plist, xamarin.mac

I have an existing .xib that needs to be displayed as the main page in a Xamarin.Mac application.  If I set the "Main Interface" as this existing .xib, it does display but it's not done by the time my DidFinishLaunching override gets called. This is where I expect to do some initialization, but the outlets I specified are all null.

I am new to Xamarin and I'm trying to figure out if I need to override a different call that lets me know that the main page is done loading or if the issue lies elsewhere.

I did see that an NSWindowController has a WindowDidLoad override, but if I set the Main Interface in the info.plist, how does it know what the ViewController is for that view so that my override WindowDidLoad gets called?

I'm thinking I probably need to create the main window manually in DidFinishLaunching, but I can't find any documentation on how to create the main window through an .xib.  There is documentation on how to get a storyboard from a nib, but I am not seeing anything on loading a .xib.  If someone can find a good reference on how the main window gets initialize (with all the plumbing included) in a Xamarin.Mac application, that may be enough.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chain of events is roughly:

- Main invokes NSApplication.Main
- Reads Info.plist to determine what xib/storyboard to load.
- Storyboard is loaded and inflated. The view controller has a custom class that points to "ViewController"
- Your ViewController is spun up, and WindowDidLoad get called.
- DidFinishLaunching is not exactly what you are looking for.

May I suggest take a look at the documentation in question to get a better understand of the full process:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/getting_started/hello,_mac/#Anatomy_of_a_Xamarin.Mac_Application